# How to control activity in Android while its looged in and logged out?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make an android app for blood bank in android using Firebase. My home page is showing a list of donner with there city and contact no. but the problem is when user is logged in and then going back to the home page where he/she can see the list of donner the app stops.

For better understanding I'm giving my whole class code here. Can anyone please help me in this process? Thanks in advance.

```
package alik.com.pmscs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import alik.com.loader.Information;

public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

Intent intent;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
ListView listView;
ArrayList <Information> informations;
Firebase firebase;
ImageView call;
//FirebaseUser user;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener listener;
GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions;

DatabaseReference reference;
NavigationView navigationView;
com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter <Information> adapter;

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    listener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user=auth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user==null){
                Menu menu=navigationView.getMenu();
                menu.findItem(R.id.nav_signoutfrom).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.nav_profileon).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.nav_adddonnor).setVisible(false);
            }

        }
    };


    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

    final FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference=database.getReference();
    reference.keepSynced(true);
    adapter=new FirebaseListAdapter<Information>(
            this,
            Information.class,
            R.layout.donorlist,
            reference
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Information model, int position) {

            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.donnor_blood)).setText(model.getBloodgroup());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.donor_name)).setText(model.getName());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.donor_contact)).setText(model.getContact());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.donor_city)).setText(model.getCity()+", "+model.getCountry());

        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);




    ColorDrawable colorDrawable=new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#bc212b"));
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_page, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_reg) {
        // Handle the camera action
        intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegisterAccount.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //finish();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
        intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //finish();

    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_profileon) {

        if(listener!=null){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This Feature is Comming Soon!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Login First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
    else if(id==R.id.nav_adddonnor){
        if(listener!=null){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DonnarRegistration.class));
            //finish();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Login First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_signoutfrom) {

        if(listener!=null){
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sign Out Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Login First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(listener!=null){
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(listener);
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();

}
}
```

My Login Class code is here

```
package alik.com.pmscs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Button btnSignup, btnLogin;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    ColorDrawable colorDrawable=new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#bc212b"));
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sign Up");

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);


    auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterAccount.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // there was an error
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There is an error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (password.length() < 6) {
                            inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, HomePage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
}


}
```

So the problem is when I am logged in then trying to go back to my Homepage activity it stopped. So I need help from experts to solve it. It'll be a pleasure if you help me in this task.

My gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: please post stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change your Login activity as follows? Here, I'm checking if the user is already logged in in the Login activity, and if it is I'm calling the HomePage activity.

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Button btnSignup, btnLogin;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, HomePage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    ColorDrawable colorDrawable=new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#bc212b"));
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sign Up");

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterAccount.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // there was an error
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There is an error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (password.length() < 6) {
                            inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, HomePage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this can match your requirements

Comment: No it's still not working as i expected.after login it still stopes :(